# org-latex-preview on entering insert mode in spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs, latex

I use Spacemacs and org mode for writing latexified notes.
There is no custom setup, just the default latex layer.

I usually toggle `org-latex-preview` by `C-c C-x C-l`. It is annoying, because I must press this combination before editing each formula.

I want it to behave like this: when I enter `INSERT` mode while on a previewed LaTeX image, it should de-preview only this formula.
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Not what you want, but it might help: try binding `org-latex-preview` to a shorter key sequence (e.g. a function key); that should make the toggling far less painful.

Comment: [`texfrag-mode`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) replaces the latex preview of orgmode with that one of the AucTeX package `preview.el`. If you enter a LaTeX fragment with the mouse or with the keyboard it is opened. If you also activate `texfrag-show-last-mode` you even see the last rendered image while editing the LaTeX source code. `texfrag-mode` is available via [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/texfrag).

Comment: I will try texfrag, but having some problems with installation. If I manage to install and it works well, and if you put that as an answer, I will accept (if no one comes up with something better in the meantime).